# Dialog message doesn't work

Tags: android, listview, android-alertdialog

I have this array

```
String[] values = new String[] { "Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile", "Blackberry", "WebOS", "Ubuntu", "Windows8", "Max OS X", "Linux", "OS/2" };
```

i need to show the elements in ListView and adapter and when i click on some element in dialog message i need to show what element is clicked.

```
public class zadaca1 extends ListActivity {


 String[] values = new String[] { "Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile", "Blackberry", "WebOS", "Ubuntu", "Windows8", "Max OS X", "Linux", "OS/2" };
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       // setContentView(R.layout.layout_zadaca1);


        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,values));

        ListView listView=getListView();
        listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder= new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
                        builder.setTitle("Delete entry");
                        builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete this entry?");
                        builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                // continue with delete
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        });
             //   builder.setMessage(((TextView)view).getText());
                builder.show();

            }

        });

    }

}
```

but when i run on my phone and click on some item it says unfortunately zadaca1 has stopped.

i also try

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder= new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
```

and

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder= new AlertDialog.Builder(AlertDialog.Builder.this);
```

but this code shows errors

Comment: `Dialog message doesn't work` Define **doesn't work**. `this code shows errors` **which** errors? LogCat, please?

Comment: in logcat what is the error is is showing post logcat message

Comment: try `AlertDialog.Builder builder= new AlertDialog.Builder(zadaca1.this);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try this and it works fine

```
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder= new AlertDialog.Builder(zadaca1.this);
                            builder.setTitle("You clicked on");
                             builder.setMessage(((TextView)view).getText());
                            builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    // continue with delete
                                    dialog.cancel();
                                }
                            });
                 //
                    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                    dialog.show();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the item inside the listview by :

```
TextView nameyouWant = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.idofyourItem);
```

Display alert Dialog inside ClickListener :

```
            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {

            //fetch data inside the listview item
            TextView Title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.idofyourItem);
            String someTitle = Title.getText().toString();

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(YourActivityName.this);

                //delete button
                builder.setPositiveButton("Delete", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                       //do some stuffs here!
                    }
                });
                builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
                builder.setTitle("Delete ?");
                builder.setCancelable(false);

                AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                dialog.show();


            }
        });
```